# Semantic UI dropdown selected text and value seems odd

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui, dropdown

Is it normal behavior that Semantic UI dropdown 'get text' and 'get value' returns two duplicate texts and values (comma delimited)? Here you can see what I'm talking about:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pybmPw

```
$('#ddl').dropdown();

function getSelectedTextValue() {
    alert( $('#ddl').dropdown('get text') + " : " + $('#ddl').dropdown('get value') );
}

//get text output: Articles,Articles
//get value output: articles,articles
```

I can't figure out why this is/should be happening. I'd expect just a single text/value..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jlukic @ github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI:

> The select gets converted into a dropdown. The dropdown call should be on the dropdown not on select after it is converted.

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3816#issuecomment-195660912

Makes perfect sense.

Comment: according to this example i should use "ui.dropdown" as selector...but what if i have multiple dropdowns?

Comment: I had a similar problem and it turned out I was updating my select list multiple times, inadvertently appending values to it, causing my 'get value' call to give me dupes. Just using my #id for the dropdown worked fine after that - `$('#id').dropdown('get value')`